# Fallout 3 crashes when updated to version 1.7?

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-3

When I install Fallout 3 and play it as it is, the game is alright, but when patch it to 1.7, I can't play it anymore.

Here is the message box:

> fallout3.exe ordinal not found.
>
> The ordinal 5359 could not be located in the dynamic library `C:\program files(x86)\bethesda softworks\fallout 3\fallout3.exe`

I just want a complete gameplay without crashing in certain areas, maybe with DLC's on my 2nd game. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a couple of websites this issue lies with "**Games for Windows Live**".

Start off with trying to install [this mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout3/mods/1086/).

> **This program allows you to do the following to Games for Windows LIVE in Fallout 3:**
>
> - Stop Games for Windows LIVE from running in Fallout 3 and prevent its
>     dll files from loading which reduces the time it takes for Fallout 3
>     to startup.
> - Remove the "LIVE" button at the main menu.
> - Allow you to
>     bind the "Home" key to whatever action you want.
> - Allow you to move
>     all of your DLC's out of their "hidden" G4WL folder and into your
>     Fallout 3 folder.

If this doesn't help then I suggest checking so that all the distributables required to play the game is installed properly.

Try [DirectX End User Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35).

Comment: will try this at once

Comment: Great. If you run into any issues then be sure to let us know.

Comment: Does installing fose also fix the problem above?